# Looping thru Directories and Files and saving Files in new directories with different names

Tags: r, loops, directory, subdirectory

I´ve got the following problem and as far as now i did not find an applicable answer.

I´ve got loads of datasets stored in subfolders in the following directory:

```
C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation
```

the subfolders are follwing this pattern:

```
/Model 1/Model_1_250skew1mar1
```

with possible changes in Model from 1 to 3; as well as 250 into 750; skew 1 to 3; and mar 1 to 3.

For example: `/Model 3/Model_3_750skew2mar2 or /Model 2/Model_2_250skew3mar1`

In those subfolders I got my datasets: `M1_1` thru `M1_1000` or for Model 2 `M2_1` thru `M2_1000`

Now I want to get my datasets: `M1_1` thru `M1_1000` and replace the missing values and save those data sets in a new directory according to where I got them:

```
C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/   NA   /Model 1/Model_1_250skew1mar1
```

I am able to do this for one of my subdirectories with the follwing code:

```
files_M_neu <- list.files(path="C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/Model 1/Model_1_250skew1mar1", 
                       pattern="M1_*[^list].dat", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

dir.create("C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/NA")
dir.create("C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/NA/Model 1")
dir.create("C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/NA/Model 1/Model_1_250skew1mar1")

for(i in 1:length(files_M_neu)){
  data <- read.table(files_M_neu[i], header=TRUE)
  fix_missing <- function(x) {
    x[x == 999] <- NA
    x
  }
  data <- fix_missing(data)
  write.table(data, paste("C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/NA/Model 1/Model_1_250skew1mar1/data[",i,"].dat"), 
              sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  rm(data)
}
```

How am I able to automate this process, so that I do not have the above code 54 times? I´d like a clean way to: get my files, replace the missings and save the files according to the directories from where I got them.

As you might guess, I am new to R but I have tried different things now and I don't see a way to get any closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution which uses `list.dirs()` to recursively read all the directories under wd, then creates the same directories tree under wd/NA/, and at last uses `dir()` or `list.files()` with full relative names to process files and save them under wd/NA/ each to its directory:

```
# set wd to work with relative path ./
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/Data Generation/")

# get the list of all directories:
dirList = NULL
for (d in list.dirs(path = ".", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)){
  dirList = rbind(dirList, d)
}

# create the directories tree in ./NA/ 
for (d in dirList){
  dir.create(paste0('NA',gsub("\\.", "", d)), recursive = TRUE)
}

# process files and save with full path to ./NA/
for (f in dir(path = ".", pattern = '*\\.dat$', full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)){
  data <- read.table(f, header=TRUE)
  data <- fix_missing(data)
  write.table(data, paste0('NA',gsub("\\./", "/", f)), 
              sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  rm(data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot!!